# Can anyone remind me of the name for the inter-scapular space on the back?

Tags: human-anatomy

It's one of those names which are often said not to exist, like philtrum.

Comment: ELU deals with:— Word choice and usage; Grammar; Etymology (History of words’ development); Dialect differences; Pronunciation (phonetics and phonology, dialectology); Spelling and punctuation. Biology.SE actually have a [human-anatomy] tag.

Answer (score 3):

"Inter-scapular space" is defined as the space between the scapulae.  It was most likely created by doctors who had no name for the space.  Yet another expansion of the English language by those who have need of a word or phrase to describe something that has no word or phrase already.  I found no other definition.

Comment: They do have a word, I just can't remember it; that's why I defined it as inter-scapular space.

Comment: @Michael - actually, in surface anatomy, it's called the interscapular area (as you can see [here](http://www.ijdvl.com/article.asp?issn=0378-6323;year=2010;volume=76;issue=6;spage=725;epage=725;aulast=Rao).